# Scheduled todo-list

Tags: android, ios, todo

Im looking for a software that lets me:

- Schedule different todo-lists to display at different times.
- No user inputs should be needed once set up.
- Preferably works on android and/or iOS tablet.

Scenario:
Wakes up and looks at wall mounted tablet for the list of morning tasks. Later, comes home from work and looks at tablet for evening tasks.

I found an add-on for desktop firefox called [simple browsing schedule](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-browsing-schedule/) that does the job when combined with asana.com. However, it is dependent on using a desktop windows/linux/macos operating system.

Comment: "`No user inputs should be needed once set up`" - how do you tick off the tasks which you have done? Or reschedule those which you haven't? Etc

Comment: @Mawg 
It shouldnt need any user input to do things like unlocking device and going into the scheduled todo-list. It would be convenient to be able to tick off the tasks but it is not a deal breaker for me if I have to do it through a more fleshed out UI on a web Browser or similar. I guess software that would allow me to display a certain web page (with to-do list) at a certain time would also be enough.

Comment: "`software that would allow me to display a certain web page (with to-do list) at a certain time`" sounds like a `cron` job, or Windows scheduler, or Android equivalent - you didn't tell us which operating system your wall mounted tablet is running; nor did you tell us  a budget, or use the [tag:gratis] tag if you don't want to pay. Please read [ask]; no offence meant, but the more info that you give us, the better that we can help you.

Comment: I have changed the question somewhat. I dont know of any convenient way to make a cron job on android do what is asked though.

Comment: There are quite a few Google Play Store hits for `cron`, also for `automate`. I am having F-Droid questions, so can't check there, but you can look. Maybe @Izzy knows of something, now that you have updated the question?